# select element in a column A while column B does not have a value

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to select products as long as it does not contain 0 in x.
Input:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['a', 0],
        ['a', 3],
        ['a', 4],
        ['b', 3],
        ['b', 2],
        ['c', 1],
        ['d', 0]
    ]
)

test.columns = ['product', 'x']

test.query("select distinct (product) where x not in (0) ")
```

expected out come:
b,c

How to do this in both pandas and SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `pandas` can do with `isin`

```py
test.loc[~test['product'].isin(test.loc[test.x.eq(0),'product']),'product'].unique()
Out[41]: array(['b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

Or do with `set`

```py
set(test['product'].tolist())-set(test.loc[test.x.eq(0),'product'].tolist())
Out[47]: {'b', 'c'}
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you would use:

```
select product
from t
group by product
having min(x) > 0;
```

This works assuming `x` is never negative.  A more general formulation is:

```
having sum(case when x = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter your dataframe, you can use `groupby` with `.any()`:

```py
test[~test.groupby('product')['x'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(0).any())]
```

Output:

```
product   x
      b   3
      b   2
      c   1
```

If you only want to see unique values you can add `['product'].unique().tolist()` at the end of the code which I pasted above.

Then we have the output:

```py
['b', 'c']
```